# nbconvert jupyter notebook to pdf (with color)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert a jupyter notebook into a pdf.

I am able to get this done with the `jupyter nbconvert MyFile.ipynb --to pdf`, BUT the output strips all the color in my text. Not to mention my bullet point formatting gets ruined too.
  nbconvert pdf - https://i.stack.imgur.com/y72b5.jpg
  original nb - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIY1R.jpg

I did a fair amount of searching and wasn't able to find anything. Can someone point me into the right direction here? I don't know what to search for at this point

Edit: Here is some of my latex/markdown code

````
**(Joyce, 2017 Chapter 4)** April 3rd, 2019

> A <font color='#0b7c29'>**group $G$**</font> has an underlying set, also denoted $G$, and a binary operation $G\times G \rightarrow G$ that satisfies three axioms.```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issues using `jupyter nbconvert`, I tried a plugin called `Ipypublish`, I works perfectly and has some quite good features (very easy to use):

Installation : `pip install ipypublish`

Simple conversion : `nbpublish -pdf -lb example/notebooks/Example.ipynb`

**UPDATED**:

Jupyter converts a notebook to PDF by converting it to LaTeX, and then using your local latex to convert it to pdf, so if both `nbconvert` and `Ipypublish` resulted in the same issue, the problem is with you local `Latex`, so here's the way to check and fix it:

> 1- `jupyter nbconvert example.ipynb --to latex`
>
> 2- then you can use your local latex to convert it to PDF and debug the file (`latex example.tex`), you can even use [overleaf](https://overleaf.com) to make that conversion online if your Local latex is missing some libraries or something

To know more : [Documentation](https://ipypublish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

Comment: I am getting an error 
`ERROR:pdf-export:pdf conversion failed: Try running with pdf-debug flag

ERROR:nbpublish:Run Failed: pdf conversion failed: Try running with pdf-debug flag`  I try running with pdf-debug flag but that doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: add this to your conversion command `--pdf-debug` so you can see where's the issue exactly

Comment: Well it seemed to process with --pdf-debug without changing anything, but it converted exactly the same as nbconvert to https://i.stack.imgur.com/y72b5.jpg

Comment: I got this error after converting to LaTex `ERROR:nbpublish:Run Failed: Notebook does not appear to be JSON: '\n% Default to the notebook output styl...` I guess I am just formatting my notebook poorly to begin with...? Is there any resources I can check for better formatting tips?

Comment: Yes the issue is definitely is the notebook itself, I would suggest looking into the raw .ipnb file using a text editor. You might be able to just find the error by having a quick look. I have done this in the past and found there was a "diff" in there, resulting from a bad/unfinished Git conflict. If I was of any help please accept my answer ;)